# Can I specify in Makefile that some files are source files?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

A tool is used to compile idl.   When test.idl has been compiled, we get test.idl.h & test.idl.cc
  I wanna recompile idl when we update it. But now I encounter a cyclic dependency:

```
                Test.idl.cc  => Test.idl             ( use tool to generate Test.idl.cc )
                Test.idl     => Test.idl.o           ( It's a implicit rule !!! )
                Test.idl.o   => Test.idl.cc
```

Then, some weired things would happen.

What can I do to fix it? It's hard to modify tool to change output filename in practice .

Can I specify *.idl be source file? Then make will ignore the implicit rule?

Comment: I don't really know anything about IDL, but I fail to see how a circular dependency is logically possible.  How can the C code be generated from the IDL and vice versa?

Comment: just a tool to compile *.idl to *.idl.{h,cpp}

Comment: Oh, I've just understood your problem.  Forget my previous comment.

Comment: It may be worth posting a simple Makefile to clear up the confusion.  For example, `test.idl.cc: test.idl  <newline> touch $@` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

But that won't help, right?  The problem is not that `Test.idl` is only generated, the problem is that the same name is used for a generated file and for an input file.

There is no fix for that, you need to change either the source file name or the compiled file name.

One good way would be to get rid of the `.idl` from the downstream components.

*Update:*

Aha, well, you can cancel the implicit rule that exists for making a no-extension linked file from a .c file. Just define a pattern rule with no recipe, as described [here in gmake docs.](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html#Canceling-Rules)

Comment: Hi DR.  My output is Test.idl.o. It's used to generate binary by:   
               g++ -o BINARY a.o b.o Test.idl.o